# ImageView not getting width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following  XML code:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/applogo1" />


       </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

According to this code, `imgOffer` should get the entire width of it's parent `tablerow`

But the image width is not changing ( see images below )

*It works fine when I hard-code the width (say 150dp)*

**What am I doing wrong here ??**

[image: table row]

[image: image view]

Comment: @nitinkumarp the 200dp is for height, i'm talking about the width

Answer (score 1):

this seems to solve it, use weight instead of width:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/applogo1"  />
```

source [TableLayout with layout_width=matchparent not matching parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714388/tablelayout-with-layout-width-matchparent-not-matching-parent)

Answer (score 1):

use android:src="@drawable/applogo1" instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/applogo1"

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:src="@drawable/applogo1" />
```

**Edit**:
Use weight for imageview instead of giving match parent and try once

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug, but it seems to work if you use weight 1 and width 0dp.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
            android:layout_weight="1" <<<<<
            android:layout_width="0dp"  <<<<<
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/applogo1" />


   </TableRow>
```

Comment: what does weight do ?

Comment: It assigns importance to views. So if you've got three views, for example, you can give them all the same weight and they'll be equally distributed. You can assign a 'weight_sum' to your parent object too to denote how much they should all add up to if you want them all to fill the view.

Comment: So here, where you are giving it a weight of 1, it is essentially saying "match_parent".